# How to convert a few datetime.datetime values to datetime.time values in a pandas df column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

After trying for too long myself, my question:
I have a df with 20.000 rows. One of the columns contains the time (H:M:S) a patient was admitted in the hospital.

Allmost all values are of type: datetime.time. Example: 09:45:00.

A few are of type: datetime.datetime. Example: 1899-12-30 00:00:00.

df.info() gives Object as type for the entire column

How to convert these few datetime.datetime values to datetime.time?  I tried these. No errors, but at the same time, no changes in type....

```
import datetime as dt

for idx, value in enumerate(df.Opnametijd):
    if type(value) == 'datetime.datetime':
        value = pd.to_datetime.time, format='%H:%M:%S'.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

and:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(df.Opnametijd):
    if type(value) == 'datetime.datetime':
        df.loc[idx,value] = pd.to_datetime.time, format='%H:%M:%S'.apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

I also tried to delete the rows where not of type datetime.time, but this didn't work as well:
(index_names is of type: pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index)

```
index_names = df[ df'Opnametijd'] != 'datetime.time'].index
type(index_names)
df.drop(index_names,inplace=True)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!
greetings Jan

Comment: datetime object like `1899-12-30 00:00:00` sounds like data's coming from an Excel import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply a lambda function that returns the time part of a datetime object *if* the element is an instance of the datetime class, otherwise leaves the element as it is.

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [datetime(2021,1,1,1,2,3).time(),
                         datetime(2021,1,1,1,2,3)]})

# df['t']
# 0               01:02:03
# 1    2021-01-01 01:02:03
# Name: t, dtype: object

df['t'] = df['t'].apply(lambda x: x.time() if isinstance(x, datetime) else x)

# df['t'] 
# 0    01:02:03
# 1    01:02:03
# Name: t, dtype: object
```

Side note: pandas built-in datetime datatype does not handle date and time separately. If you want to use that (which I think can be more convenient than the standard lib's datetime.time), you *must* provide a date (can be arbitrary if you're not actually using it for something).

Comment: thanks! but... it gives this error:: TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types. Any idea?

Comment: @Janneman: did you make sure to use the same imports as I did in the example? "datetime" might be used differently in your code. Other than that, your time column might be composed differently- can you provide a [mre] with the question?

Comment: Hey. You were absolutely right! Your code works after I used the same imports! many thanks and greetings Jan